# Notepad++ How to delete sections of text starting with a line containing a certain phrase

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I'm trying to edit a few calibre files that have tags attached, but the tag line is not always formatted the same.

Eg.

```
div class="pcalibre1 pcalibre2 pcalibre tags-list"

div class="pcalibre1 pcalibre2 tags-list pcalibre".
```

I want to delete everything including and between the lines containing tags-list and entry-speaker.

Is there an easy way to do this with regex?

Comment: Might be quick to use `Mark` in a plain old search, bookmark marked lines and then delete them.

Comment: Better give an example of text that you like or not to delete.

Comment: What is `entry-speaker`?

Answer (score 0):

As @harrymc said, we need a better example. But here is a quick workaround.

```
Do not delete

div class="pcalibre1 pcalibre2 pcalibre tags-list"
  Things to delete
  blah
  blah
  blah
div class="pcalibre1 pcalibre2 tags-list pcalibre".

Do not delete
```

**Regex:**

```
^div\s+class=.*tags-list.*^div\s+class.*tags-list.*\r\n
```

**disclaimer**: this is just basic regex (a start). you can build upon it.

Make sure you check the box **'Matches New line'** in **Search Replace Window**.

[image: notepad++ search replace match new line regex]

Comment: Have a try witth: `div class="do not delete"\nblah\ndo not delete\ndiv class="tags-list"\nblah\ndiv class="tags-list"`